# React Native Fetch not working with laravel API Locally

Tags: javascript, php, react-native, fetch, laravel-5.7

I am trying to fetch laravel API locally in react-native.When I try with remote url it works but it's not working with local server.I am using android studio emulator and

```
react-native => 0.59.8, 
laravel => 5.7
```

My Code

```
 async submit() {

    //https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json => this works

    try {
        let response = await fetch('localhost:8000/api/coins');
        let responseJsonData = await response.json();
        console.log(responseJsonData, 'data');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e, 'error')
    }
};
```

Error

```
05-20 14:46:08.167  4749  8885 I ReactNativeJS: { [TypeError: Network request failed]
05-20 14:46:08.167  4749  8885 I ReactNativeJS:   line: 24115,
05-20 14:46:08.167  4749  8885 I ReactNativeJS:   column: 31,
05-20 14:46:08.167  4749  8885 I ReactNativeJS:   sourceURL: 'http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false' }, 'error'
```

Comment: So are you running Laravel on Android? If not, use the IP address of your computer. Android will have its own IP and localhost won’t relate to your PC.

Comment: Can you try this `let response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/coins');`

Comment: hi @Objectobject. I had already tried with that one.

Comment: Why did you just delete the question that I correctly answered for you?

Comment: Hello @Nick. That was the wrong question. I am creating a new one. I am extremely sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Might be an issue

iOS is running in a simulator and Android is running in an emulator.

In your `localhost:8000/api/coins` `localhost` is pointing to the environment in which the code is running.

The emulator emulates a real device while the simulator is only imitating the device.
So `localhost` on Android is pointing to the emulated Android device. And not to the machine on which your server is running.

**Solution**
The solution is to replace `localhost` with the IP address of your machine. (Eg:  192.168.1.22)

Answer (score 0):

For iOS you have to set Domain Exception:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <false/>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>cocoacasts.com</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

or allow all Domain:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: hi @Vikram , I am having problem with android.